# WHat addField type i should use?

Tags: laravel-backpack

At first, example tables:

Products:

- id
- name
- price

Promo:

- product_id (to Products id foreign)
- old_price
- new_price

What type of field i should use to get a price from foreign item selected before?
price value to old_price

Field where i select a product:

```
$this->crud->addField([
         'label'     => 'Product',
            'type'      => 'select',
            'name'      => 'product_id',
            'entity'    => 'products',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            
            //'model'     => "Backpack\Products\app\Models\Products",
    ]);
```

Promos model function:

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Products::class,'product_id','id');
}
```

I tried to use a select2_ajax but i got a route problem (error 404).

Answer (score 0):

As a promo has at least one product you can say type relationship with the exact namespace of your model.

```
$this->crud->addField([
     'label'     => 'Product',
     'type'      => 'relationship',
     'name'      => 'product_id',
     'entity'    => 'products',
     'attribute' => 'name',
     'model'     => 'Backpack\Products\app\Models\Products',
]);
```